# Decay rate of the Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

Suppose that $f \in C^n(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\partial^{\alpha} f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $|\alpha| \le n$. Show that
$$ |\hat{f}(k)| \le \frac{C}{(1+|k|)^n} $$
for some constant $C$.

I used the relation $\widehat{\partial^{\alpha}_{x} f}(k) = (-\mathbf{i}k)^{\alpha} \hat{f}(k)$ which gives
$$ |\hat{f}(k)| \le \frac{D \| \partial^{\alpha}_{x} f(x) \|_{L^1} }{|k^{\alpha}|} \le \frac{C}{|k^{\alpha}|} $$
But I can not show that $|k^\alpha| \ge (1+|k|)^n$.

Update: Actually, we can show that
$$ |k^\alpha| \le max_{i=1,2,\cdots,d}\{ |k_i|^{|\alpha|} \} \le |k|^{|\alpha|} $$
So I guess a better estimate is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f \in L^1$ and $\partial^\alpha f \in L^1$, so the bound is direct from $$(1+|k|^n)|\hat{f}(k)| \le C \sum_{\alpha \le n}|k^\alpha\hat{f}(k)| \le C\sum_{\alpha} \| \partial^{\alpha} f \|_{L^1} $$

Comment: How did you get $|k|^{\alpha} |\hat{f}(k)| \le \|\partial^{\alpha} f \|_{L^1}$? Note that $|k|^{\alpha} \ne |k^{\alpha}|$.

Comment: @AlanZhang I meant $|k^\alpha|$..

Comment: So you mean $ (1+|k|^n) |\hat{f}(k)| \le C \sum_{|\alpha| \le n} |k^\alpha| |\hat{f}(k)|$, but why does this inequality hold?

Comment: @AlanZhang Because it is obvious : $|k|$ large implies some $k_m$ are large, try with $d=2$

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much.